# Adding an onmouseover attribute to an <asp:Panel> in a <asp:Repeater>

Tags: c#, repeater, panel, webforms, onmouseover

I have a repeater containing several several panels.
I have noticed that there is no onmouseover attribute of the `<asp:Panel>`.
I have read that I can add the attribute to the panel by calling in the page_load:

```
PanelID.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "Script to Run");
```

The problem is that I am in a repeater, and the PanelID is generated by asp.net like ContentPlaceHolder_ctl01_myID_0 so not only it is hard to figure out, but VS2010 does not recognise it as a proper object and throws an error on it, plus I have to attach it on every item, so I need to use a for or foreach, but I don't know what to iterate on.
Is there a way like

```
foreach(childcontrol in Repeater.ChildControlsISpecificallyNeedPossiblyIdentifiedBySomeID)
{
 childcontrol.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "Script to Run");
}
```

to do this in C# in the Page_Load eventhandler?
I want to run a client side onload, onmouseclick and onmouseout on the panels too, so I want to attach those attributes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking outside the box, instead of specifying the `onmouseover`-attribute inline using ASP.NET, you can attach the javascript event listeners *in javascript*.

Give the panel a CSS class:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="panel"></asp:Panel>
```

Using jQuery, the syntax to bind the event handlers would be as follows:

```
$(".panel").mouseover(functionToRun);
```

If you're not using jQuery, you'll need a bit more code, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

panel is represented with `div` on client side, you can get the client side id by using `SomePanel.ClientID` however if you are referring to the triggering panel you can always use `this` in the JavaScript

would not put all the event handlers on each element

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute to the panel in the event of repeater onitemdatabound and find the control in that, as this event will called for each and every time the row is bound so that you dont have to call it foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using ItemDataBound event.

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {   
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item){
       Panel pnl = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("myPanel");   
       pnl.Attributes.Add"onMouseOver", "yourFnctionName()");
    }
}
```